# A faster algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I was told to write an algorithm as following
There are three arrays A[],B[],C[] of same size N.Find out all possible (i,j,k) such that A[i]+B[j]=C[k]. The maximum allowed time complexity is O(N^2).Following is the algorithm I written for O(N^2)

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000

struct sum
{
        int result;
        int i;
        int j;
};

int main()
{
        struct sum sum_array[MAX];
        int n=4;
        int a[] = {4,1,2,5};
        int b[] = {1,7,6,0};
        int c[] = {11,3,8,2};
        int k;
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
                sum_array[i].result=-1;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                        sum_array[a[i]+b[j]].result=a[i]+b[j];
                        sum_array[a[i]+b[j]].i=i;
                        sum_array[a[i]+b[j]].j=j;
                }
        }
        for(k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
                if(sum_array[c[k]].result==c[k])
                {
                        printf("<i,j,k> = <%d,%d,%d>\n",sum_array[c[k]].i,sum_array[c[k]].j,k);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

My question is how to do it faster ? Any O(N*logN) or better algorithm for this ?

Regards,
Arka

Comment: Are you looking for all possible (i,j,k)? Or you just want to find a triple? Also your arrays data are distinct?

Comment: Your code doesn't find *all* combinations.  If there is more than one pair of {i,j} that gives the same sum, then you will only capture one of the them.

Comment: Also your current solution is totally wrong. It has too many bugs.

Answer (score 6):

The maximum answer is of size N^3 and therefor no better complexity can be achieved.
Take this example A={1,1,1,1,1,1,1} , B = {1,1,1,1,1,1} C = {2,2,2,2,2,2} You approach will not output all the possible triplets for the above example.

Comment: +1: Nice simple answer.  (This is correct unless there's some constraint, e.g. that the elements in each array must be unique.)

Comment: Even if there is a constraint that all the elements are distinct, there is an example where the answer is of size O(N^2): a={1,2,3,..n}, b={1,2,3,...n} c={1,2,3,..n}

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for one combination or just number of such combinations then:

Let `MAX` be maximum element from arrays `A`, `B`, `C`.
My solution is `O(MAX log(MAX))`.

**I'm describing just idea without details.**

Lets `A_count[x]` = number of elements `x` in array `A`.
Calculate such arrays for `A`, `B` and `C`.
It can be done in linear time.

Think of arrays `A_count`, `B_count` and `C_count` as polynomials. If there is `A[i] + B[j]` that sums to `X` then `A_count * B_count` (multiplied as polynomials) has `coefficient[X]` != 0.

So now idea is simple. Calculate `A_count * B_count` and compare their coefficients with coefficients of `C_count`. Calculating `A_count * B_count` can be done in `O(MAX log(MAX))` using  [Discrete Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Polynomial_multiplication).

@edit, example on

```
int A[] = {4,1,2};
int B[] = {1,0};
int C[] = {3,8,2};
```

Lets calculate A_count, B_count, C_count

```
                 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
int A_count[] = {0, 1, 1, 0, 1};
int B_count[] = {1, 1}; 
int C_count[] = {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
```

Now lets calculate A_count * B_count. Simple algorithm for multiplication:

```
for(int i=0; i<A_count_SIZE; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<B_count_SIZE; j++)
        mult_result[i+j] += A_count[i] * B_count[j];
```

But it can be done faster (by [Discrete Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Polynomial_multiplication)).

```
int mult_result[] = {0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1}
```

It means that:

```
1 pair sums to 1
2 pairs sums to 2
1 pair sums to 3
1 pair sums to 4
1 pair sums to 5
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this approach. Can you provide an example? (Either code or hand-calculation.)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Could you tell me which part you don't understand ?

Comment: This doesn't tell you what the tuples are.

Comment: That's why I started my answer with sentence: 
`If you are looking for one combination or just number of such combinations then:`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find for existence of triplets (i,j,k) such that `A[i]+B[j]=C[k]`, then it can be done in `O(n^2 logn)`. Also, you can find count of such triplets by using this method.

- Make a new array `D[]`, such that `D` holds sum of every possible pair of `A` and `B`. This will make size of D = n^2.
- Sort array C. Now, `binary search` for all values of `D` in array `C`. Time complexity is `O(n^2 logn)`.

To count number of triplets,

- Find the `lower bound` and `upper bound` for values of `C[]` in `D` only if that value exists in `D` (which can be checked using index returned by lower bound function).

  count += upper_bound_index - lower_bound_index;

Time complexity of this is also `O(n^2 logn)`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find anything faster than O(N<sup>2</sup>), simply because you have to loop through all of A for each B to get the sums of all the array elements. That alone is O(N<sup>2</sup>), preventing you from getting anything faster.

EDIT: Although, there is some optimisation to be done. For example, you set `sum_array[a[i]+b[j]].result = a[i]+b[j]`. Later you test if the key is equal to the result. How can it be anything but equal?